# Search terms that start with a period break core search module

Tags: 7, search

Setup:

- Core search module
- Apache web server w/ mod_rewrite
- Default .htaccess that ships w/ Drupal

When searching something that begins with a period, like ".ssh", this .htaccess rule takes effect and 403's the request:

`RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]`

The rule is intended to prevent users from viewing otherwise hidden files and directories, like a .git directory.

However, the core search module injects the search query directly into the URL like so:

`http://sample.com/search/node/.ssh`

So Apache thinks I'm trying to access a hidden file, and I get a 403 before Drupal is even bootstrapped.

I couldn't find much related to specific issue for the core search module, so I'm curious if anyone has any opinions on how to resolve this? If the core search module instead appended the search as query string params, then it would be OK, but since it puts it in the URL structure directly, it causes this issue.

Comment: This should be a bug report on the core search module, not a question here.

Comment: Yes good point. At the time I was looking for someone to point out to me a quick fix or something, but it appears that's not the case. Issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/2329481